# Matching Combination

Tags: sql, combinations, matching

I have a table which has multiple transaction numbers with amounts. If i need to get a matching combination of a particular amount from these transactions. How do i get it?

For example:

Table:

[image]

And i need the list of transactions summing to amount 30. How can i get it? If not a closest amount to 30

Is that possible through SQL?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two transactions, you can use:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from transactions t1 join
     transactions t2
     on t1.txn < t2.txn
ordre by abs(50 - (t1.amount + t2.amount))
fetch first 1 row only;
```

You haven't specified your database, so this uses standard SQL.